# Configure antd theme in react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-boilerplate

I am trying to configure antd theme in react-boilerplate. I saw the issue [2027](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2027) in react-boilerplate repo. This is exactly what I want but I tried the given configuration in the accepted answer and it doesn't work for me.

In vanilla react-boilerplate repo, I installed antd.
In the HomePage (index.js), I added a button, checkbox as

```
<Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
<Checkbox onChange={onChange}>Checkbox</Checkbox>
```

My `webpack.base.babel.js` looks like

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js');
const themeVariables = lessToJs(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './../../app/theme.less'), 'utf8'));
```

and one of the rule is

```
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              modifyVars: themeVariables,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

The `theme.less` file is

```
@ant-prefix: ant;

@primary-color: #ff0000;
@btn-primary-color: #ff0000;
@checkbox-color: #ff0000;
@checkbox-check-color: #ff0000;
```

I tried overriding any possible colour in Button or Checkbox but couldn't get the theme colour changed.

Is there something I am missing? I have been stuck at this point from a long time. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: I have been working with react and antd for almost 2 years. Please check this boilerplate https://github.com/shreyansRS/react-redux-antd  this will help you to override antd's theme variables. File "config-overrides.js" line no. 11 & 12

Answer (score -1):

Trying importing ant styles to your index.js where you're applying the styles to the entire app.

Just add the following import

`import 'antd/dist/antd.less';`

For more information you can follow antd [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme)